# apt-get - ignore CPU type?

Tags: cpu, apt

Im trying to setup a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` to get updated versions of some ruby code. My system(s) are all **armel** based but there isn't a specific build for this in the repository. How do I format the line in the **.list** file to ignore or bypass the CPU type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to modify the line in the lists file.
What you can do is install packages for specific architectures like so

`apt-get install package:arch`

So `apt-get install ruby1.9.1:armhf` will attempt to install the armhf version of ruby.

Beware though that installing packages not meant for your architecture can **severely break your system**

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how to do it the way you are suggesting it, but I do know how to do it from the command line. The appropriate command is

```
 sudo apt-get -d -o APT::Architecture="amd64" install some_package
```

This downloads (the -o option) only the package, belonging to the architecture amd64. If you think it wise to install it, you may do so with via `dpkg -i`.

Alternatively, you may use

```
sudo apt-get download some_package:amd64
```

I have never tried substituting * for the architecture, you may try that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't. Things will break horribly, since even if you manage to install the packages, your arm system would have as much of an idea of a dog in a cattery of what to do with any compiled x86 or x64 code.

Your best option (as painful as it is) would be to find a repository with this code for your plaform, or install from source (maybe maintaining a repository yourself!). While ruby itself is largely platform independent, you may have non platform independent dependencies. While I do realise keeping this up to date and maintained is a pain, its probably potentially less painful than borking up your system with random, non functional packages belonging to another architecture